# Iterations While loop syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create an iteration program. What I want it to do is:

n=5429 9542-2459=7083 n=7083 8730-0378=8352 n=8352 8532-2358 =6174 n=6174 7641−1467=6174

When i enter my code (below), idle responds  with

> SyntaxError: expected an indented block

Code:

```
number=input("enter your 4 digits number:")
print("your number is",number)
KAPREKAR_NUMBER="6174"
i=0
while number!=KAPREKAR_NUMBER:
large="".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
small="".join(sorted(number))
number=str(int(large)-int(small))
i+=1
if number==KAPREKAR_TAL:
print("it took ",i," iterations to solve the kaprekar aligoritm.)
```

Comment: Hi Im trying to create an interation program. What i want it to do is:  n=5429
9542-2459=7083
n=7083
8730-0378=8352
n=8352
8532-2358 =6174
n=6174
7641−1467=6174
 When i enter my code: idle responds by:SyntaxError: expected an indented block

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Python is whitespace sensitive, it's impossible to figure out code of any size if it's not indented properly. Give _every_ line of code an initial four space indent (to get code block formatting/syntax highlighting), then fix the relative indents to match your actual code. When you have a failure like this, it's also considered polite to post the Traceback from the exception (including the exception messge) to help people find the error faster. Odds are, the message and traceback identify the problem instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your tabs (4 spaces) in your editor.Python understands code blocks by looking at indentations.

Answer (score -1):

I've guessed at some of what you're trying to do and the following version gets rid of a few different syntax errors, including two indentation errors, and one string literal error (no closing quote).

The first error you'd encountered was due to bad intenting.  Python is very strict on indenting.  It uses indent levels to define code blocks.

```
number=input("enter your 4 digits number:")
print("your number is",number)
KAPREKAR_NUMBER="6174"
i=0
while number!=KAPREKAR_NUMBER:
    large="".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
    small="".join(sorted(number))
    number=str(int(large)-int(small))
    i+=1

if number==KAPREKAR_NUMBER:
    print("it took ",i," iterations to solve the kaprekar aligoritm.")
```

By the way, the last `if` here is redundant.  It could be deleted (and just keep the `print`), but I've included it in order to be true to the original code.

Comment: `input` on Python 3 already returns `str`; you don't need to "cast" it to `str`. You're clearly writing your code as if this is Python 2, but the OP tagged it Py3.

Comment: Side-note: On Python 2, you still wouldn't convert to `str`. You'd just use `raw_input` to avoid the unsafe/unstable implicit `eval` of Py2's `input`.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just trying to remain true to the original code as closely as I could.  I've removed that comment now.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and the program did exactly what i wanted it to do. It really helped @son of Beach.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.  Please accept the answer if it worked.   (A vote up wouldn't hurt either).   Also please take note of the comments above advising on better ways to ask your questions.  (For next time).